# MS SQL: Execute truncate if record count over N

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, query-performance, query-designer

I have a table that is a feed from another database that is pulled. Frequently enough the source database tables are not populated since the feeds are down. What I would like to do is simply perform a count of the number of records in the source database tables to make sure they are populated before pulling the data feeds since in this case data that is stale is better than all the data missing. I have done this in other databases but am not sure how to perform it in Microsoft SQL 2008.

Here is a mockup of what I am trying to get working that will eventually be put into a scheduled proc:

```
CASE 
    WHEN 
        (SELECT COUNT(PC.id) FROM [server08].[db01].[dbo].[tblesrc01] PC) > 9000 
    THEN
        TRUNCATE TABLE DartDB.dbo.assets_feed;
        INSERT INTO tbl_feed
        (
                id,name,amt,row_updated
        )
        SELECT 
              Q.PK_ID AS id
            , Q.fullname AS name
            , Q.cost  AS amt
            , SYSDATETIME() AS row_updated

        FROM [server08].[db01].[dbo].[tblesrc01] Q;
    ELSE 
END
```

Is case inappropriate for this purpose or is there something I missed?

Comment: You can use `IF` and accomplish this, like `IF (Condition) BEGIN TRUNC .... END`.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can do this in a stored proc using `IF...  ELSE` construct.
Here is the [MSDN documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) that explains how to use the construct...

Your proc should look like

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(PC.id) FROM [server08].[db01].[dbo].[tblesrc01] PC) > 9000) 
    BEGIN
        TRUNC ... 
        INSERT ...
    END
```